# How can I pinpoint the specific location where property tests fail when using QuickCheck more efficiently?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck, template-haskell

**Current solution:**

I am currently using `counterexample` function from `Test.Quickcheck`:

```hs
counterexample :: Testable prop => String -> prop -> Property
```

to add informative messages in order to know exactly where the test failed. However, let's say I have multiple properties inside a property:

```
f s = 
    counterexample "p1 s" (p1 s) .&&.
    counterexample "p2 s" (p2 s) .&&.
    counterexample "p3 s" (p3 s) .&&.
    counterexample "p4 s" (p4 s) .&&.
    counterexample "p5 s" (p5 s)
```

where `p1...p5` have type `Property`.

This hinders readability. I would love to have something like:

```
prop s = 
    ce (p1 s) .&&.
    ce (p2 s) .&&.
    ce (p3 s) .&&.
    ce (p4 s) .&&.
    ce (p5 s)
```

`ce (p1 s)`

would expand to:

```
counterexample "p1 s" (p1 s)
```

Is there any solution using `QuickCheck` library, `TemplateHaskell` or something else? Would be great to know automatically which expression failed a test without explicitly using `counterexample` function and writing the expression that is on the right side.

EDIT:

In order to clarify my question, I am adding a minimal working example:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Main where

import Test.QuickCheck
import System.Exit

-- Property 1: Reversing a list twice should give the original list.
propertyReverseTwice :: [Int] -> Bool
propertyReverseTwice xs = reverse (reverse xs) == xs

-- Property 2: The length of the reversed list should be the same as the original list.
propertyReverseLengthFail :: [Int] -> Bool
propertyReverseLengthFail xs = length (reverse xs) == length xs + 1

-- Property 3: Combining the first two properties.
prop_combined :: [Int] -> Property
prop_combined xs = 
  propertyReverseTwice xs .&&. propertyReverseLengthFail xs

return []

main :: IO ()
main = do
  passed <- $quickCheckAll
  exitWith $ if passed
    then ExitSuccess
    else ExitFailure 1
```

I am adding (on purpose) a property that never holds (property 2). Running this code gives:

```hs
=== prop_combined from /Users/detach/Haskell-Foundations/Recursion/tempCodeRunnerFile.haskell:17 ===
*** Failed! Falsified (after 1 test):  
[]
```

I see line 17 is where the error occurs. However, I don't know which of the properties failed. On the other hand, if I modify the code to include `counterexample` function:

```hs
-- Property 3: Combining the first two properties.
prop_combined :: [Int] -> Property
prop_combined xs = 
  counterexample ("propertyReverseTwice " <> show xs) (propertyReverseTwice xs) .&&.
  counterexample ("propertyReverseLengthFail " <> show xs) (propertyReverseLengthFail xs)
```

The error given is more informative (I know which property failed

```hs
=== prop_combined from /Users/detach/Haskell-Foundations/Recursion/tempCodeRunnerFile.haskell:17 ===
*** Failed! Falsified (after 1 test):  
[]
propertyReverseLengthFail []
```

So, how can I avoid writing, for example:

```hs
counterexample ("propertyReverseTwice " <> show xs)
```

every time, and instead use a shorthand using `TemplateHaskell` or some other mechanism ?

Comment: Does [`quickCheckAll`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.14.3/docs/Test-QuickCheck-All.html) do what you need? Simply rename `p1` through `p5` to `prop_1` through `prop_5`.

Comment: Thank you very much as always, @Daniel Wagner. I have seen what you suggest; however, it’s not specifically what I was looking for. I would like to test property `f s`. It is composed of many properties; p1, p2, etc... Instead of using `counterexample` function in each one of the cases to know exactly which property failed), I would like to automatically expand that using Template Haskell or some other mechanism.  The ideal would be just obtaining the name of the expression that failed.

Comment: Closely related, but not duplicates: [Is there a (Template) Haskell library that would allow me to print/dump a few local bindings with their respective names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31349556/7509065) and [Print and execute a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9498642/7509065)

Comment: Thank you @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica. For some reason, if I enable `TemplateHaskell` pragma, I have type errors. I have to use that pragma because I need `quickCheckAll`.

Comment: Enabling `TemplateHaskell` shouldn't by itself cause type errors. You should probably post a second question with a minimal reproducible example of it doing so.

Comment: @F.Zer I guess I'm not sure I understand yet why `quickCheckAll` doesn't do what you want. Doesn't it automatically expand to check all the properties, exactly the thing you are hoping `f` would do but without even needing to define `f` in the first place?

Comment: Yes, @DanielWagner. Of course, your suggestion automatically checks all properties; however, I would like to know which properties of `f` (if any) failed. That's why I am using `counterexample` function. And my goal would be avoiding to write `counterexample "p1" p1` every time, but instead use some shorthand like `ce p1` that expands to `counterexample "p1" p1` using `TemplateHaskell` or other mechanism. Do you have any idea about this ?

Comment: @F.Zer In my small experiments, `quickCheckAll` already tells you which properties failed and which passed, and even which file and line to look at to see the relevant property. What am I missing?

Comment: Thank you again @Daniel Wagner for looking into this. Just added an extensive explanation to my edit and a minimal working example. Are you seeing the same as myself ? Does this clarify my question ?

Comment: I followed your suggestion, @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica. Here it is my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77931843/printing-an-expression-using-dump-library-fails

Comment: Based on this and [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77931843/126014) you seem to be struggling getting a good test workflow going. It looks to me as though you're trying to implement something from scratch that's already provided by higher-level APIs. Another option (the one that I use) is to write the properties as functions and use a 'proper' unit testing framework to run and report assertion failures. Here's a small example code base: https://github.com/ploeh/FizzBuzzHaskellPropertyBased

Comment: I saw it, @MarkSeemann. Thank you. I do wonder about this: I see you are typing "Divisible by both 3 and 5" and I had hoped that I can derive a stringified representation of the property being tested (to save some time). Does that make sense ?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by that...

Comment: Sorry if I explained incorrectly, @MarkSeemann. I mean: if I can derive a stringified representation of the property being tested, like: “reverse (reverse xs) == xs” I can save some time. Now, I can see that your approach is more elegant, and many times makes more sense to describe and be a little more explicit about what a property tests. Like: “Reversing a list twice is equal to the original list”. Is this more clear ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way, short of some LLM, to do that. Properties may be arbitrarily complex, so how should that work? Here's an example of a property of intermediate complexity: https://github.com/ploeh/UserManagement/blob/master/Haskell/test/Spec.hs#L18-L28

Comment: @F.Zer As mentioned in my very first comment: simply rename `propertyReverseTwice` to `prop_ReverseTwice` (and `propertyReverseLengthFail` to `prop_ReverseLengthFail`). Then you can delete `prop_combined` entirely and have all the features you asked for.

Comment: Thank you, @MarkSeemann ! Those examples shed light into this issue. Now, it's clear that the path I am following can't be generalized.

Comment: I appreciate your insight, @DanielWagner. I see that I even know the actual argument that caused failure.